# Move any word that starts with x, y, or z to the front of the arraylist - wrong output

Tags: java, arraylist

I need gone through arraylist and remove to the front all words that starts from `x` `y` or `z`.

But my testing output shows that this method have some logical bug.

**Code:**

```
/**
   * Moves any word that startw with x, y, or z to the front of the arraylist, but
   * otherwise preserves the order
   */
  public void xyzToFront()
  {
      int insertAt = 0;
      but otherwise preserves the order
      for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {     
          String temp = list.get(i);
          if (temp.startsWith("x") || temp.startsWith("y") || temp.startsWith("z")) {
              list.remove(i);
              list.add(0, temp);
          }
      }
  }
```

**testing output:**

```
Actual: [yak, zebra, xantus, ape, dog, cat] - what is after executing
Expected: [xantus, zebra, yak, ape, dog, cat] - what we should have
```

How to solve this trouble?

Comment: what is the input of list?

Comment: @Kostia see `actual` on `testing output:`

Comment: I mean actual input not actual output.

Comment: The 'actual output' matches your specification.

Comment: Did i get that right, that your actual on output is the exact same as intput and nothing happend at all? If so are you sure your `temp.startsWith("?")` is working correctly?

Comment: I don't get the question. If I execute your code with the "Actual" input, the list looks exactly like "Expected".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your method, which inserts every next word starting with x, y or z before previous, and actual and expected output, I think you want to insert the words to the front of the list in order in which they were removed. If that's the case, you could just use a counter variable and insert the next word after previously removed. For example:

```
public void xyzToFront()
  {
      int insertAt = 0;
      but otherwise preserves the order
      for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) { 
          if (temp.startsWith("x") || temp.startsWith("y") || temp.startsWith("z")) {    
              String temp = list.get(i);
              list.remove(i);
              list.add(insertAt++, temp);
          }
      }
 }
```

Comment: I'm not sure about this to my mind this should be as my example, change to `i = 1` and after this `list.add(insertAt, temp);` at this order. I'll clarify this order question.